# How do I translate null values from database to DbSet and back in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database that has been used to store nullable `ThingType?` enum as integer values:

```
public enum ThingType
{
    Good = 0,
    Bad = 1,
    Annoying = 2,
}
```

But that has meant custom code to accommodate null values elsewhere in my project.  I want to modify my enum to have a "Not Specified" value for `ThingType`, as defined below:

```
public enum ThingType
{
    NotSpecified = -1,
    Good = 0,
    Bad = 1,
    Annoying = 2,
}
```

What's the best way to implement this translation in EF without making changes to the database, so that `null` row values are translated to `ThingType.NotSpecified` and `ThingType.NotSpecified` is inserted as a `null` value?

Comment: I'd say: great opportunity to turn nullable database fields into `not null` (with a little conversion) and use the new enum. Whether you test for `null/HasValue` or for `> NotSpecified` in the code doesn't make much difference. Moreover, it's more expressive. After all, `null` may also mean: oops, forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second property

```
// Map this one to DB
public ThingType? ThingTypeDb
{
    get { return ThingType == ThingType.NotSpecified ? (ThingType?)null : ThingType; }
    set { ThingType = value == null ? ThingType.NotSpecified : value.Value; }
}

// Don't map this one. Use it in your logic
public ThingType ThingType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Downside of this is that saving the entity may cause it to write new values to the database (which may be desired)

Comment: This pattern would have to be implemented everywhere I use the `ThingType` - which is error-prone and not DRY.  I'd prefer to specify a mapping and not have to think about it ever again.

Comment: @ScottBaker EF6 does not support what you want. Either live with it or not use EF6 :)

Comment: In EF Core you could use [Value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

Comment: @IvanStoev There is seriously *no way* to define a property mapping for a given value?

Comment: @ScottBaker Nope. Seriously. EF Core have added some support for value conversions. But EF Core has it's own issues and basically is not ready for production usage.